# Strip class name from rtti

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I am writing some C++ program that I don't want the binary leak information on how the program is working.  I know we can probably strip symbols from the binary, but the class names are still stored and retrievable by RTTI information.  So how can I avoid that?  If I need to disable RTTI, what C++ features will no longer be usable?

Comment: The most common RTTI feature is `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: It sounds like you need a C++ obfuscator.

Comment: AFAIK, you could just zero out the class names in the final executable manually. They are not used for `dynamic_cast` (only the actual position and dependency info), though you cannot read the name using `typeid` then... At least that's the case for most ABIs. I don't know a switch to do so.

Comment: @Deduplicator how to zero out?

Comment: @jayatubi: You should probably look the symbol up in the debug-info first, then use a hex-editor, and afterwards roll your own script for it... Not very convenient, and there might be pre-built ones, but finding them might be difficult.

Comment: @Deduplicator Is there any such function in clang/gcc? Or do I need an extra tool to do this manually? Because I'm developing the iOS app with xcode and I'm afraid of the action may break the signature on the binary.

Answer (score 2):

What you lose when disable RTTI depends on your compiler (and compiler version).

For gcc 4.5, you could read:

> -fno-rtti Disable generation of information about every class with virtual functions for use by the C++ runtime type identification
>   features (dynamic_cast' andtypeid'). If you don't use those parts of
>   the language, you can save some space by using this flag. Note that
>   exception handling uses the same information, but it will generate it
>   as needed. The `dynamic_cast' operator can still be used for casts
>   that do not require runtime type information, i.e. casts to void * or
>   to unambiguous base classes.

For Visual Studio 2013:

> Use /GR if the compiler cannot statically resolve an object type in
>   your code. You usually need the /GR option when your code uses
>   dynamic_cast Operator or typeid. However, /GR increases the size of
>   the .rdata sections of your image. If your code does not use
>   dynamic_cast or typeid, /GR- may produce a smaller image

Thus, indeed, in these cases, it disables only `dynamic_cast` and `typeid`.

However, if the goal is to hide the behavior and some information about your executable, I don't think that `strip` and disable RTTI are the best solution. It may be a good beginning, but to have a real binary protection, you must see packer / executable protector / obfuscation tool (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_compression).

Comment: One can still use `dynamic_cast` and `typeid`, if one zeroes out the class names. Do not know any tool or compiler switch to automate that though.

Comment: `strip` does that, nop ?

Comment: I don't think so. `strip` is for removing debug info. This data is live.

Comment: You're right, `strip` only removes debug info and symbol table. Class names are in the STRTAB (string table) section of ELF. But, if you zero these strings, you can't use `typeid`: the `type_info` object returned by `typeid` will contain wrong class names.

Comment: The name is only used for printing it out, not for equality comparison/tagging/dynamic_cast. There only identity of the class_info structure is needed.